# Rotation and zooming imageview in android

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which zooming  and rotation of the image      view  is required according user finger gesture,as in some iPhone apps work.please suggest me how  can i do in android. "

Answer (score 3):

Use the following lib in your project. It is very simple to implement. You will get all geastures.
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subsampling Zoom Image View to perform Zooming on gestures of Hand
Just download and include lib in your Project,then follow instruction to implement

[Subsampling Zoom Image View](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1509)